# controlling tooltipster tooltip position for a radio group

Tags: jquery, validation, tooltipster

I have tooltipster setup to show my validation messages and by far they work well except for one case.
I have a set of radio buttons and picking Yes from Yes/no is mandatory.So I have setup a jquery validation method for the same .When I debug through firebug I can see the validation happening but the message that gets flashed is next to the **Yes** option and it kind of masks the **No** option completely as it is on top of it.

Here is how it looks

[image]

here is how my tooltipster config looks for the radio buttons

```
$('#iWatchEnabled').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
    onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
    position: 'right',  // display the tips to the right of the element
    theme: '.tooltipster-shadow',
    left:' 850px'

});
```

The last left:'850px' is an attempt to overwrite the position that I see via firebug.

Here is the firebug details for the tooltip for the radio button

```
<div class="tooltipster-base tooltipster-shadow tooltipster-fade tooltipster-fade-show" style="transition-duration: 350ms; animation-duration: 350ms; width: 298px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; top: 125.5px; left: 675px;">
<div class="tooltipster-content">Application has to be onboarded as a pre-requisite</div>
<div class="tooltipster-arrow-right tooltipster-arrow" style="">
<span style="border-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help in resolving this would be great.It looks a seemingly trivial issue but I have quite some time in trying to get this right but nothing to show for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer

It appeared that my first setting was overriding my radio group setting too.

```
$('#onboardForm input').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
    onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
    position: 'right',  // display the tips to the right of the element
    theme: '.tooltipster-shadow'
});

$('#onboardForm input:radio').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
    onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
    position: 'right',  // display the tips to the right of the element
    theme: '.tooltipster-shadow',
    offsetX: 100
});
```

I added an offset however I had to set a seperate style for the other text fields
I did so

```
$('#onboardForm input:text').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
    onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
    position: 'right',  // display the tips to the right of the element
    theme: '.tooltipster-shadow'
});

$('#onboardForm input:radio').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
    onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
    position: 'right',  // display the tips to the right of the element
    theme: '.tooltipster-shadow',
    offsetX: 100
});
```

Notice that I added a :text in my first config to suggest that the style holds good only for input type="text" elements
and in the second config (for my radio button) I added a offsetX and shifted it away by about 100 px